# Find the GCD and LCM of the factorials of two given numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, factorial

Find $\gcd(20!, 12!)$ and $\text{lcm}(20!, 12!)$.

My answer is:

$20=2^2 \times 5$

$12=2^2 \times 3$

GCD $= 2^2 = 4$

LCM $= 2^2 \times 3 \times 5 = 60$

....

But my teacher said that this symbol ! means factorial. How can I find GCD and LCM for the factorial of these numbers?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/). Also [read](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of factorial is $n!=n\times(n-1)\times\dots\times1$, or if you prefer

$$\begin{eqnarray}
0! &=& 1\\
n! &=&n\times(n-1)!\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus, if $p<q$, you have that $p!$ divides $q!$, so $GCD(p!,q!)=p!$, and $LCM(p!,q!)=q!$.

Answer (score 1):

GCD of two factorails is equal to the smaller factorial. Why? Because the factorial is equal to product of all the numbers equal to and below 'n'.
Say it was 20! And 12! . 20! Equals 20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13*(12!)
GCD[20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13*(12!),(12!)]=12!
LCM would be:
Let the lower number be x,
X!*x.